# pagination next button not working on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

what am i doing wrong? pagination isn't working and i'm not getting any error. next button isn't working. is there a solution to this?

```
class PostsIndex extends Component


    public function render()
    {
        $statuses = Status::all()->pluck('id', 'name');
        $schools = School::all();

        return view('livewire.posts-index', [
            'posts' => Post::with('user', 'school', 'status')
            ->when($this->status && $this->status !== 'All', function ($query) use ($statuses) {
                return $query->where('status_id', $statuses->get($this->status));
            })->when($this->school && $this->school !== 'All Schools', function ($query) use ($schools) {
                return $query->where('school_id', $schools->pluck('id', 'name')->get($this->school));
            })->when($this->filter && $this->filter === 'Top Exp', function ($query) {
                return $query->orderByDesc('votes_count');
            })->when($this->filter && $this->filter === 'My Exp', function ($query) {
                return $query->where('user_id', auth()->id());
            })->when($this->filter && $this->filter === 'Spam Posts', function ($query) {
                return $query->where('spam_reports', '>', 0)->orderByDesc('spam_reports');

            })->when(strlen($this->search) >= 3, function ($query) {
                return $query->where('body', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%');
            })
                ->addSelect(['voted_by_user' => Vote::select('id')
                    ->where('user_id', auth()->id())
                    ->whereColumn('post_id', 'posts.id')
                ])
                ->withCount('votes')
                ->withCount('comments')
                ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                ->simplePaginate(10)
                ->withQueryString(),
                'schools' => $schools,
        ]);
    }
}
```

i have tried my possible best could not get it to work

Comment: You forget to add parameter `public function render(Request $request)`

Comment: this is a live wire component

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the link {{ $schools->links() }} in the posts-index file

Comment: Welcome to SO!   Would you be able to add some proper code formatting and, possibly, with syntax highlighting?  You can read more about proper code formatting and syntax highlighting [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109).